# Using AWS glacier list_jobs function to list more than 50 jobs

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, boto3, amazon-glacier

I am confused about the limit parameter of the aws glacier client [list_jobs](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/glacier.html#Glacier.Client.list_jobs) function. According to the docs the limit is "The maximum number of jobs to be returned", where  "The default limit is 50". But when I set the limit to 1250 as shown below I still get back a jobList containing 50 jobs

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('glacier')
response = client.list_jobs( vaultName='myBackup' , limit='1250' , statuscode='Succeeded' )
```

Also I am confused about the marker returned by the list_jobs function. Am I supposed to call list_jobs repeatedly until the marker is the set to the string "null"?

Comment: you need to use pagination. the json returned by your request should have a `marker` field which you would then feed in to every subsequent request. also notice how the docs mention, `The number of jobs returned might be fewer than the limit, but the number of returned jobs never exceeds the limit.`

Comment: AWS can return *fewer* jobs than the specified limit, got that. BTW, what is the marker value when there are no more jobs `None` or the string `"null"`.

Comment: probably an empty string